# Numbering in some list, Java Streams foreach

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

I would like to write foreach on some array (that may contains null elements in random places) that will print to the console list of not-null elements with numbering

Lets say I have array called `personArray` that contains some Person objects. The result I expect is something like this

```
1 Name Lastname
2 Name2 Lastname2
3 Name3 Lastname3
and so on..
```

I know I can do foreach like this:

```
Arrays.stream(personArray).filter(n -> n != null).forEach(person -> System.out.print(person.getName() + " " + person.getLastname()));
```

but this will print not-null objects without ordering number

```
Name Lastname
Name2 Lastname2
Name3 Lastname3
and so on..
```

so how to "number" it? since every variable used inside lambda declared outside must be final its impossible to increment it

Comment: If the 1st and 3rd elements are not null and the 2nd element is null, do you want the 3rd element to have the index 2 or 3? (i.e. should indices of null elements be skipped?)

Comment: yes I want null elements to be skipped, in your example: 1 firstName 2 thirdName etc.

Comment: You can go around the final variable limitation by using an array with a single element to keep the counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May not be the best solution, but it's one

```
    AtomicInteger x=new AtomicInteger(1);
    Arrays.stream(personArray)
    .filter(n -> n != null)
    .forEach(person -> System.out.print((x.getAndIncrement())+""+person.getName() + " " + person.getLastName()));
```

If it's acceptable for you using an `AtomicInteger`, you could do this, being `AtomicInteger` an immutable class.

Or withouth using any variable, playing a bit with `reduce`

```
    Arrays.stream(personArray)
    .filter(n -> n != null)
    .reduce(1,(a,b)->{System.out.println(a+" "+b.getName() + " " + b.getLastName());return ++a;},(a,b)->{return ++a;});
```

Notice that inside a lambda expression you're not allowed to modify the object, but you're allowed to modify its state. This is why, in my first example, you can't reassing a new value to `x` with `new` keyword, but you can modify its state, i.e. the integer it's wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

A solution which does not create new side-effects and does not abuse the API would be to create a stream of indices:

```
IntStream.range(0, personArray.length)
         .map(idx -> (idx+1) + " " + personArray[idx].getName() + " " +
                     personArray[idx].getLastname())
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

There are also some third-party libraries which allow you to represent the stream of index-value pairs. One of such libraries is my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
EntryStream.of(personArray) // creates stream of Entry<Integer, Person>
           .mapKeys(idx -> idx+1) // Add one to indices
           .mapKeyValue((idx, person) -> idx+" "+person.getName()+" "+ person.getLastname())
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick to avoid this problem.
Let's create an array of `int`s with size 1.

```
int[] number = {1};
```

And then when printing, you can use it like

```
System.out.println((number[0]++) + " ...");
```

---

**Here is a working example:**

```
int[] number = {1};
Arrays.stream(personArray)
    .filter(n -> n != null)
    .forEachOrdered(person -> System.out.println(
        (number[0]++) + ". " +person.getName() + " " + person.getLastname()
    ));
```

Note, that I replaced `print` with `println`.
I also changed `forEach` to `forEachOrdered`, because the former does not guarantee to keep the order of encounter.

Comment: how is it possible that object existing in array can be incremented while standalone cant?

Comment: The trick is, that an array is an object that you instantiated just once. So you can change the content, but not to the object itself. You could also create a new class that contains an integer that you can edit from outside; and using this trick, you could also handle different types than `int`.